# Leaflet-JS Not sure what is wrong with my script below

Tags: leaflet, javascript

I have posted a screenshot of my index.html and JavaScript files. The issue is that no webmap is displayed. Only the head (h1 in my html) is visible to me. Any thoughts on this?

[![enter image description here] [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlW8r.jpg)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlW8r.jpg)

[![enter image description here] [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YU2yu.jpg)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YU2yu.jpg)

Comment: Always post plain text code rather than screenshots. Otherwise the code cannot be searched and found.

Comment: Also,  the title is not descriptive and should be improved to reflect the actual problem.

Answer (score 2):

In your html, Just you need to rename `mapid` to `map` .. and rewrite your Javascript code.

.. or include the following line

`<div id="mapid" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; display: block;"></div>`

**UPDATED**:

Use this basic template:

please, use this template just to check that leaflet is working okay: Check here the results https://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start/example-basic.html

````
<html>
<head>

    <title>Quick Start - Leaflet</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.4.0/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-puBpdR0798OZvTTbP4A8Ix/l+A4dHDD0DGqYW6RQ+9jxkRFclaxxQb/SJAWZfWAkuyeQUytO7+7N4QKrDh+drA==" crossorigin=""/>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.4.0/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-QVftwZFqvtRNi0ZyCtsznlKSWOStnDORoefr1enyq5mVL4tmKB3S/EnC3rRJcxCPavG10IcrVGSmPh6Qw5lwrg==" crossorigin=""></script>



</head>
<body>



<div id="mapid" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>
<script>

    var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

    L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw', {
        maxZoom: 18,
        attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
            '<a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
            'Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
        id: 'mapbox.streets'
    }).addTo(mymap);

</script>



</body>
</html>```
````

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I made the changes but still it looks like my JavaScript file is not connected. No map display, except the heading (h1).

Comment: I have updated the asnwer. check it

Comment: This is really useful. However I found the main problem with my map is my css file and that is weird. I have a separate css file as such:
#mapid{height:500px;} It only accept height in pixels and if you add width or show the height in percent or width in percent, then the map disappear. Not sure why its like this. 

Although I can give a style to my h1 in the css file.

Answer (score 1):

You need a CSS file or a `<style>` element that includes a specific height for the `mapid` element. I.e.:

```
#mapid { height: 400px; }
```